# about downloading android sdk

Tags: android, sdk

I am learning about android.
I have downloaded Eclipse and Adt .
Now I have to download Android sdk. Should I download SDK as standalone tool or with Android Studio.
What is SDK and what all does it include?
Can I use both Eclipse and Android Studio with Sdk

Answer (score 1):

Is better to use just Android Studio, this is the official Android Development IDE.

https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/sdk/index.html

Android Studio help you to download Android SDKs.

Answer (score 1):

> What is android sdk ? What does it include ?

It stands for Software development kit, and as the name suggests , it contains the platform (android version specific libraries to help you make apps for android platforms).

It contains different tools to help you install apps (adb tool), collect statistics and view information about the apps running in your devices etc.

Download [sdk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) here

> Can I use both Eclipse and Android Studio with Sdk ?

Yes you can , just have to point these ide's to the sdk's absolute path.

> Should I download SDK as standalone tool or with Android Studio ?

You can do it either way, the former would require you to give its path to the ide you will be using, either Android Studio or eclipse.

**Note** 
Android studio is the best and developer's guide by google recommends the same as well.

[Some features of android studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The SDK means Software Development Kit and is there for building android apps.
The sdk contains all the libraries you need to run your code on an android device.

Therefore eclipse and android studio can use the same sdk.

I really recommens using androi studio tho.
It is way better for developing android apps and comes with the sdk.

Eclipse was used some time ago but now android studio is the official ide for android,  and way more powerful than eclipse.

Comment: I am learning from a book and it requires Eclipse.I already downloaded Android sdk as a standalone tool but it is not working. maybe there has been some error in downloading. What all does the sdk folder contain

Comment: Everything you can do with eclipse you can do with AS.  Do yourself a favour and use AS.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK is a software development kit that is used to create Android applications.

You can download Android SDK as standalone and use it with eclipse to develop your android Apps.So you do not need to download Android Studio to develop Android Apps although it is recommended for starters.

You can download Android sdk only from [here](http://filehippo.com/download_android_sdk/) Or [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=en-GB#top)

Also, The final step before you develop your android applications is to make sure that your `android-sdk-tools`,`android-sdk-platform-tools`,`support-tools`, and your API s are up to date.Check out your **SDK Manager** "Don't forget to run as administrator".

Comment: I already downloaded Android sdk as a standalone tool but it is not working.what must be the reason

Comment: the path to those tools must be given in the eclipse or studio

Comment: I gave the location of sdk in eclipse but it doesn't recognize it

Comment: @Alice Have you updated your support tools and downloaded the sdk-platforms?